# Git merge request Как использовать код из ещё неодобренного merge request'а

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-merge

Допустим, есть GitLab и мне нужно сделать две задачи и для каждой создать отдельный мерж реквест. Для первой задачи я создаю ветку из мастера, что-то в ней делаю и создаю мерж реквест обратно в мастер. Потом начинаю делать вторую задачу, опять создаю ветку из мастера, но уже хочу использовать код из предыдущей ветки, из того мерж реквеста, который ещё не одобрен. Как быть? 
Может для выполнения второй задачи надо было создать новую ветку из предыдущей?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы работаете над большим проектом с полным циклом разработки в команде то вы ОБЯЗАНЫ дождаться слияния (после всех правок) и продолжить ветвление (в вашем случае от мастера).

Представьте какой ад начнётся если 10 разработчиков начнут вносить новую функциональность не в проверенный отлаженный код с внесёнными правками, а прямо в свою ветку одновременно исправляя баги, исправляя логику и допиливая тесты.

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически, смысл мерж реквеста именно в том, что его могут "одобрить" и влить в мастер, или "не одобрить", и отправить на доработку.

Получается, что использовать код из предыдущего мерж реквеста в следующей задаче можно только на свой страх и риск.

И сделать это можно и так, как Вы предлагаете - из предыдущей ветки - или, можно из мастера создать две ветки, а потом смержить реквест с мастером (после одобрения) и со второй веткой (можно сразу, наверное)